# Rails SpreeCommerce Internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Hello i want to change language of Spreecommerce and i add (following documentation https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n) gems

to **Gemfile**

```
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree/spree_i18n'
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail'
```

but if i run `bundle install` im getting error

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0) ruby

    rails (= 3.2.14) ruby depends on
      activerecord (3.2.14)
```

My version of spreecommerce is stable 2.0, my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-0-stable'

# Lokalizace
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree/spree_i18n'
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

i tried this `gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree/spree_i18n', branch: '2-0-stable'` too but no difference, what now ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your error states

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    globalize3 (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0) ruby
```

ActiveRecord is component of Rails.

Your Gemfile states:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
```

Which is showing that your project is using Rails 3.2.14, but one of your gems requires Rails 4.0.0.

The gem in question is:

```
gem 'globalize3', github: 'svenfuchs/globalize3', branch: 'rails4'
```

You should modify this one to use a Rails 3.2.x compatible version, and run `bundle install` to fix this issue.